# Disadvantage of ES6 and CommonJS export convention

Tags: node.js, import, ecmascript-6, export, commonjs

For the `main` file of an `npm` module, as defined by the `package.json`, I was considering a pattern like this:

```
import Struct from './src/struct'

module.exports = Struct
module.exports.default = Struct
```

In order to support both CommonJS and ES6 imports:

```
const Struct = require('my-module')
// or
import Struct from 'my-module'
```

Are there any downsides to this convention that might cause unintended problems?

The issue I'm trying to address is having to force consumers of the package to stick to ES6 or CommonJS because both of these seem rather unsavory:

```
const Struct = require('my-module').default
// or
import * as Struct from 'my-module'
```

Upon considering this further, would defining my class in `/src/struct.js` like this be preferable?

```
export default class Struct {
  static get default () {
    return Struct
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: What type is `Struct` in this case? Generally I'd recommend avoiding adding properties onto objects that aren't defined in that same file, but you can probably avoid that depending on what it actually is. Also since compilers usually add logic to automatically make CommonJS modules work with `import`, what issue are you specifically trying to avoid?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Well, `Struct` is simply a class with functionality I'd like to package as an npm module, so adding a `default` static property doesn't seem very harmful. Perhaps I should make it non-enumerable or something to avoid accidentally enumerating it?

Comment: Babel will use `module.exports` as default export if the imported module is CommonJS, so I don't see how `module.exports.default = Struct` helps. Do other bundlers not do that?

Comment: @FelixKling wait really? I thought babel stopped doing that in v6

Comment: I thought this was something else... I could be wrong. Are you saying Babel will simply import `undefined` in that case? I can't image it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Lets look at what Babel does when you do `import foo from 'bar';`](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=JYWwDg9gTgLgBAMwhRUIjgcgEYEMqYDcQA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0):

```
'use strict';

var _bar = require('bar');

var _bar2 = _interopRequireDefault(_bar);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
```

You can see that, depending on the "type" of the imported module, Babel will either import the `default` export, or it will import `module.exports` (because `require('bar')` returns `module.exports`.

That means, in order for your module to be importable as

```
const Struct = require('my-module')
// and
import Struct from 'my-module'
```

All you have to do is

```
module.exports = Struct;
```

Answer (score 1):

`default` exports aren't very convenient in Node.js applications because

```
const Struct = require('my-module').default;
const { default: Struct } = require('my-module');
```

`require`s are cumbersome and harder to read than

```
const Struct = require('my-module');
```

Due to how the interoperation with CommonJS modules works in current Babel, TypeScript (with `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` option) and Node native support for ES modules (.mjs modules), it's recommended to export a function like:

```
module.exports = Struct
```

so it could be imported as

```
import Struct from './src/struct';
```

in ES modules, and as

```
const Struct = require('./src/struct');
```

in CommonJS modules.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I was wondering if you had a comment on this. I've read recently that some implementations treat `import * as Struct from 'my-module';` more like `const { ...Struct } = require('my-module')`, which has the effect of preventing functions, constructors, and primitives from being exported as the `module` object. Is this a legitimate concern, or is it just superstitious programming?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Can you provide a link for this statement? I have several possible issues with ES module implementations in mind but not sure which of them may be an issue here. I would expect no problems with `*` import, it's quite consistent in implementations.

Comment: [Here's one](http://www.thedreaming.org/2017/04/28/es6-imports-babel/) notice that in commonjs if you `module.exports = () => {}` and in ES6 you `import * as foo from '...'` then `foo` is not callable.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I see, also checked Felix Kling's answer as well which was posted after mine. I don't remember why I answered like that, possibly referred to earlier Babel version. I wonder why nobody cared to downvote the answer. Any way, things are different these days, partially due to how Node implements native modules (AIK it doesn't care about __esModule like transpilers do). I updated the answer to not confuse anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since nodejs still doesn't have native support for ES6 modules, for now it's really just a matter of code readability. But IMO it's no need to support both CommonJS and ES6 modules. Stick up to one.

Comment: I realize there isn't native support for ES6, but that isn't the point. It is _extremely_ common for consumers to be using babel, webpack, rollup, browserify, and other bundling services that ignore the limitations of native support by transpiling source code from future specifications. I don't want to force people using these configurations to use one of the awkward `import * as Struct from 'my-module'` like I said above, as that's not a very conventional or expected way of using `import` in ES6.